# Disable Animation between pages

Tags: animation, swiftui

This is my first time working with Swift / SwiftUI.

I have several seperate screens in different documents. Like one for the sign up, one for the main menu, and so on.

I am just always running into a few problems.

1. How can I disable the transition animation (a slide) from one page to another?
2. How can I disbale the apperance of this "back" symbol on the upper left corner?
3. How can I disable the option to go back to the last page through sliding?

I tried working with .transition and a few other options. But even ChatGPT couldnt quite help me. Partly because it always wants me program all of my screens in one single document.

This my current code for pressing on a button, and changing the screen:

```
Button(action: { // home button
    if userInput.isEmpty {
        navigateToReviewScreen = true
    }
}) {
    Image("home")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
}
.padding(.horizontal, 20)
.background(
        NavigationLink(destination: MainMenuView(), isActive: $navigateToReviewScreen) { EmptyView() }
            
)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Why use NavigationView if you don’t want anything that comes with it? ChatGPT is of little help with SwiftUI it is years behind and is missing all the improvements that have been made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out finallly.

Here is how:

Direct State-Driven Navigation:

Instead of relying on NavigationLink for navigation, which inherently includes the default slide animation, we use state variables to control which view is displayed. This approach directly changes the view based on state changes without any built-in animation.
Using Conditional View Rendering:

The main view contains conditional statements (if-else) that render different views based on the state variables. When a button is pressed, it changes the respective state variable, and the body of the view re-renders to show the new view immediately.
Eliminating NavigationLink for Transition:

By not using NavigationLink for transitions between different views, we avoid the default transition animations that NavigationLink provides in SwiftUI.
Programmatic Navigation Triggers:

Buttons or other UI elements are used as triggers to change the state variables. These triggers cause the view to switch without the need for an animated transition.
Immediate View Update:

When a state variable changes, SwiftUI immediately updates the view hierarchy to reflect this change. Since we're not using any animation modifiers or transition effects, the change appears instant and without the default sliding animation.
Flexible and Controlled Navigation:

This method offers more control over the navigation flow in the app. It allows for a seamless and instant transition between different views based on the app's logic, user actions, or other conditions.

And a general code example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showFirstView = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if showFirstView {
                FirstView(switchView: { showFirstView = false })
            } else {
                SecondView(switchView: { showFirstView = true })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FirstView: View {
    var switchView: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("First View")
            Button("Go to Second View", action: switchView)
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var switchView: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Second View")
            Button("Back to First View", action: switchView)
        }
    }
}

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```